# Как сделать переход с одной страницы на другую при нажатии на кнопку в react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

class Inputs extends Component {
   state = {
      password: ''
   }

   handlePassword = (text) => {
      this.setState({ password: text })
   }
   login = ( pass) => {
      alert(' password: ' + pass) 
   }
   render() {
      return (
         <View style = {styles.container}>  
         <Text style= {{color:'#7a42f4',  paddingTop:'38%', textAlign:'center', fontSize:'30', fontWeight: 'bold'} }>Exchange</Text>
         <Text style= {{color:'#000',  paddingTop:'30%', paddingLeft:'33%', fontSize:'20'} }>Аутентификация</Text>
            <TextInput style = {styles.input}
               underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
               placeholder = "Токен"
               placeholderTextColor = "#9a73ef"
               autoCapitalize = "none"
               onChangeText = {this.handlePassword}/>
            
            <TouchableOpacity
               style = {styles.submitButton}
               onPress = {
                  () => this.login(this.state.password)
               }>
               <Text style = {styles.submitButtonText}><Text style= {{textAlign:'center'}}>Отправить</Text></Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
         </View>
      )
   }
}
export default Inputs

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
      paddingTop: 23
   },
   input: {
      top: 10,
      margin: 15,
      height: 40,
      borderColor: '#7a42f4',
      borderWidth: 1,
      textAlign: 'center'
   },
   submitButton: {
      top: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#7a42f4',
      padding: 10,
      margin: 15,
      height: 40
    },
   submitButtonText:{
      color: 'white'
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу посоветовать использовать в целях навигации эту библиотеку https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/
В документации найдите раздел Stack Navigator. Это именно то, что вам нужно.
А так же советую заранее продумать (не в деталях) структуру навигации в приложении, изучить тему Nesting navigators. При должном желании с вопросом организации навигации можно разобраться за пару-тройку часов.